# Format Date not to a String

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I want to format the current date to this pattern `dd.MM.yyy`. At this time, I use:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date now = new Date();
String start = dateFormat.format(now);
```

And I must do this for a lot of dates. The problem is that I need the formatted date as `Date`, not as a `String`.

I don't find out, how this is possible in a easy way (there are about 150 - 200 dates to format).

Comment: Whats your input? String? And you want that as Date? SimpleDateFormat has "public Date parse(String text, ParsePosition pos)"

Comment: The `java.util.Date` has NO format. Formatted Dates are just their `String` representation

Comment: @pimpf0r: What input? Yes as i wrote, i need it as `Date`

Comment: Meaningless. A `Date` isn't formatted. A `String` is formatted. Nor a real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is used to convert a `Date` into a `String`

```
String myFormattedDate = dateFormat.format( someDate );
```

representation or a `String` into a `Date`

```
Date myDate = dateFormat.parse( someString)
```

Internally a `Date` is just a long millisecond value so you can't view it as a formatted string unless you use a formatter of some kind.

As for there being a lot of dates, 200 will take millisecond to process so don't worry about that.

Comment: All date handling in Java is nasty, Joda Time is not a bad library but it doesn't work with JPA. Hopefully they'll fix it in Java 8 but I'm not holding my breath. Any chance you could tick the accept answer mark, cheer.

Comment: @wobblycogs. Joda Time does work with JPA. I've done that by using EclipseLink Converters.

Comment: @Rohit Jain Although we use EclipseLink as the implementation we depend only on what JPA 2.0 (as specified in JavaEE 6) provides. It looks like JPA 2.1 has introduced converters though so I'll be upgrading to Java EE 7 soon.

Answer (score 2):

Then use `dateFormat.parse(start);`

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date now = new Date();
System.out.println(now.toString());
String start = dateFormat.format(now);
Date after = dateFormat.parse(start);
System.out.println(after.toString());
```

Output :

```
Thu Jun 20 11:01:12 CEST 2013 
Thu Jun 20 00:00:00 CEST 2013
```

Comment: So i convert a date to string and then again to date. No nicer way?

Answer (score 0):

But, what do you want? what do you expect?
A date is just miliseconds, you can't have a date formatted. You can parse it from a string (with the SimpleDateFormat), you can show it in a parsed way (in string), but underneath, you only have a miliseconds.
So, you can have 20.06.2013 by

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(now));
```

If you just want a date without hours, minutes and seconds, then use ZouZou approach. Or JodaTime.

Comment: Yes I know `Date` are just milliseconds. But when you print a Date, then it get Formatted automaticly, so maybe there is a easy way to format that. But now i understand how it is possible. Thank you for your alternatives, but must use Date, because this date's are also used in other classes...

Comment: Then, instead of using `date.toString()` use the SimpleDateFormat to output.